# Как подключить библиотеку в c++, linux

Tags: c++, linux, библиотеки

День добрый! Собственно такой вопрос, есть у меня библиотека буст, ее я установил через терминал, все отлично. Но вот мне понадобилась библиотека urdl. Я скачал архив и вопрос такой, куда эту папку из архива закидывать?

Уже голову сломал, прошу помогите. В исходник прописывал вот таким образом:

```
#include "/media/user/backup/cpp/urdl/http.hpp"
```

В итоге результата нет.

Comment: `результата 0` что конкретно значит - не находит файл (ошибка компиляции) или не может найти библиотеку (ошибка линковки) ?

Comment: Если Вы ради этой библиотеки ставили такого монстра как boost, то это зря... Зачем Вам необходима данная библиотека? Скачивать контент с использованием адресов URL? Так уже априори стандартом является тот же curl. Его могли без всякого буста поставить из репозитория через apt-get или aptitude. Хотя, если я не ошибаюсь, он уже включен во всех дистрибутивах по умолчанию. Curl хорошо документирован, кроссплатформенен и ему не требуется буст.

Comment: Тогда собственно такой вопрос, куда именно скидывать папку с файлами?

Comment: Какую папку? Распакованную? Я же указал, в ответе куда ее распаковывать. Что с ней потом делать? Да ничего. После ребута она удалиться - она больше и не нужна. Все собранные/скомпилированные файлы будут располагаться по разным папкам в системе. Для хэдер файлов это могут быть _/usr/include/итакдалее_ или _/usr/local/include/итакдалее_ . Аналогично для библиотечных файлов есть папки _/usr/lib_ и _/usr/local/lib_ . От дистрибутива к дистрибутиву могут быть отличия. Поищите у себя по имени файла.

Comment: Вообще, если собираетесь работать с linux/unix, то желательно изучить структуру папок и какая для чего нужна. А также желательно изучить как компилировать библиотеки. Потому как, например, при обновлении ядра, Вы может быть ничего и не заметите. А вот Ваша программа может не пожелать запускаться и нужно будет перекомпилировать ее и сопутствующие библиотеки. И возвращаться к этому вопросу будете снова и снова.

Comment: @Corle, вы не ответили на мой вопрос, и абсолютно не ясно что у вас за проблема. Для работы с библиотекой вам нужны 2 вещи - заголовочные файлы (`.h` либо `.hpp`) и скомпилированная библиотека (что-то вроде `.so`) в принципе путь к библиотеке не важен, её можно подключить откуда угодно, по умолчанию это `/usr/include` для хедеров и `/usr/lib` для `.so`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А Вы уверены в том, что достаточно просто будет скопировать папку? Возможно ее (библиотеку) необходимо сначала собрать/скомпилировать?

Распакуйте сначала архив в папку ***/tmp*** (данная папка чистится после ребута, что удобно). Посмотрите в распакованной папке наличие файла ***Makefile***.

Если он есть, тогда в терминале, находясь в распакованной папке, наберите и запустите последовательно:

***make***

***make install***

Если сборка из исходников пройдет успешно, то, как правило, все нужные компоненты раскидываются по правильным директориям. Но скомпилированные файлы (либы) остаются также и в Вашей распакованной папке. Оттуда можете их взять себе в проект.

Также, как правило, можно до сборки указать папку для установки (например так)

***configure --prefix=/usr/local***

Обращаю внимание, что все действия выполняться должны с должными правами. Если тот же configure не хочет запускаться (но он есть в папке), то посмотрите на его (файла) атрибуты и при необходимости измените их.

Вообще, лучше прочитать, там где взяли исходники, про их использование и подключение к своей программе. Не все так просто может оказаться, как Вы бы хотели и как я описал :)